# Generate an image from an HTML code/file in .NET Core 2.x Console Application?

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-core, nreco

I've currently a problem with the [NReco.ImageGenerator](https://www.nrecosite.com/html_to_image_generator_net.aspx) in a .NET Core 2.x console application that I can't get an image because of course, the console application is not web service at all.

**My question now is:** Is there a way to use a somehow web service in a console application so I can generate an image from an HTML code/file or is there any other solution to generate an image from HTML code/file in a .NET Core 2.x console application?

### Edit

It works on .NET Standard but not on .NET Core.

```cs
var html = string.Format("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
var converter = new HtmlToImageConverter // Exception happens here
        {
            Width = 250,
            Height = 70
        };
var bytes = converter.GenerateImage(html, NReco.ImageGenerator.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Exception:

```cs
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpContext' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
at NReco.ImageGenerator.HtmlToImageConverter..ctor()
at SESL.Modules.SESL.User.UserImage() in E:\Source\SESL-Discord\SESL\Modules\SESL\User.cs:line 36
```

Comment: I am a bit confused, but the console application can call a web service or a web request and return either a stream or byte[] of data for you to handle however you want.  Could you provide more information?  Like some code?

Comment: I'm guessing the OP might not realize that a console application can call a web service or a web request and read the response stream.  Hence my reply below.  Personally, I'd just use `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`.

Comment: @Greg I added a code block and the exception.
@paulsm4 I would do the same but the problem is, it's not depended on `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` but `System.Web`

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to execute the NReco.ImageGenerator from within the console application itself, ie. the generated is hosted by the console application. You don't want to have a web service host the generator and have the console application connect to it via HTTP Client.

Comment: @Adrian Yes, it should be in the same console application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out, that the [NReco.ImageGenerator](https://www.nrecosite.com/html_to_image_generator_net.aspx) does not support .NET Core and for the .NET Core I need to pay the LT version.
But I discovered another NuGet Package which does somehow the same but I need to draw the image by myself. Therefore the alternative is [Magick.NET](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET)